# The order of restitution of the elements of a map not changed is always the same?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
map<vector<int>,int> > mymap
```

I wonder if the order of items in a map can change if over mymap  does not do anything. That is, suppose that the map has 3 pairs  that I call 1 2 3 and when I  go into the map whit this code :

```
for(auto i = mymap.begin();i!=mymap.end();i++)
{
    cout<<i->first<<endl; //operator<< is redefenid
}
```

the element are returned in this order: 3 2 1
Later without making any changes to the map with the same code above I have the assurance that the elements are accessed in the same  order as before (namely 3 2 1)?
(I use C++11)

Comment: There are always in lexical order according to key (that you should not change).

Comment: @Jarod42 So if I do not do destructive operations on the containers I have the guarantee that the order of restitution of the elements is the same?

Comment: @Umbert you are trying to say that if you do not touch the container used as key in the map and do not even touch that then it is guarantee that the order of restitution of the elements will be same!

Comment: If I have understood your query correctly

Comment: @Deepanshu You understood well

Answer (score 0):

Then you need [std::unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/)

Comment: Why?  If the OP does not change the map it will always be printed the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In a `std::map<Key, Value, Comparer>`, elements are ordered according to `Key` and `Comparer`. `Comparer` should still give the same result for 2 given keys, and key should not be modified (from `Comparer`'s point of view).

So, if you iterate once and have `key1 < key2 < key3`
then even after addition/removal, you still have these relative order: `key1 < keyA < key2 < keyB < key3`
or if you only remove `key2`: `key1 < key3`.